# SQL query to find averages

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created three tables such that

```
CREATE TABLE guest(

name varchar(100),
ranking int,
PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE room(

 roomname varchar(100),
 wallcolor varchar(100),
 rating int,
 PRIMARY KEY(roomnane)
 );

 CREATE TABLE reservation(

 name varchar(100),
 roomname varchar(100),
 day varchar(100),
 moveinday int,
 moveoutday int,
 PRIMARY KEY(roomname, day, start, finish),
  FOREIGN KEY(roomname) REFERENCES room(roomname),
  FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES guest(name)
 );
```

I am trying to create two queries

1. For each reserved room, list the average ranking of guests having
   reserved that room. I am having trouble listing the average for each room. Here's what I have tried

   ```
   select reservation.roomname, AVG(guest.ranking)
   from reservation, room, guest
    where reservation.roomname == room.roomname AND reservation.name = guest.name
   ```

This does not provide the desired result. How could I fix my query?

2. Query to verify that there are no conflicting reservations for rooms. (same room can't be reserved for multiple people over moveinday and moveoutday. I am not sure how to start for this

Comment: Why are you storing what looks like date type information as varchar(100) and moveinday and moveoutday as integers?

Comment: You will have a truly dreadful time trying to manage date and times if you use varchars and integers. Room reservation system must use dates it is core to the purpose of a reservation. I also suggest you have a table of integers (sometimes called a "tally table") which is very useful for your query 2

Comment: and why is a guest ranking not in the reservation table? what happens if the same guest stays more than once, in different rooms, and wants to rank each? Is this question homework?

Answer (score 2):

Dont forget about `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT reservation.roomname, AVG(guest.ranking)
FROM reservation, room, guest
WHERE reservation.roomname = room.roomname 
AND reservation.name = guest.name
GROUP BY reservation.roomname
```

Comment: SQL does not use `==` for equality; also, why not use proper SQL-92 explicit joins?

Answer (score 1):

You should learn to use proper `join` syntax and table aliases.

```
select r.roomname, AVG(g.ranking)
from room r join
     guest g
     on r.name = g.name
group by r.roomname;
```

In addition, the `room` table is not actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

As for your second question, the basic should be such a join:

```
select room.roomname 
from room
join reservation r1 on room.roomname = r1.roomname 
join reservation r2 on room.roomname = r2.roomname
```

and then the where clause is the complicated part:

```
where (r1.moveinday < r2.moveinday and r1.moveoutday > r2.moveoutday)
or (r1.moveinday < r2.moveinday and r1.moveoutday > r2.moveinday)
or (r1.moveinday < r2.moveoutday and r1.moveoutday > r2.moveoutday)
```

The 1st case: r1 totally contains r2.

The 2nd case: r1 overlaps the move in day of r2

The 3rd case: r1 overlaps the move out day of r2

you might want to use <=, >=, depends how you consider this case. If you like to use <=, >= (instead of <. >), I recommend you add a unique ID to each reservation, as you will have to add to the where clause something such as 
r1.ID <> r2.ID